# Read (decode) and process an aac stream with python

Tags: python, audio, decode, aac

I have an Axis camera that provides an audio stream that is aac encoded. I would like to find a possibility to decode that stream in Python to further process the raw audio data. Does anybody have suggestions how that could be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) to convert an `aac` audio to datasegment and then process it further.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

#convert audio to datasegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("your/path/to/audio.aiff", "aac") 
play(sound)  #play sound
```

Lots of other data manipulation using `pydub` is available [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)